# Differences between IsDigit and IsNumber in unicode in Go

Tags: unicode, go

It seems IsDigit and IsNumber in the unicode package don't behave differently, at least in my following test code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "unicode"

func main() {
    r := rune('1')
    fmt.Println(unicode.IsDigit(r))
    fmt.Println(unicode.IsNumber(r))
    //true
    //true
}
```

They both print `true`.

I tried to understand from their source code. However, I still don't understand what the differences are between them, even from their source code.

```
// IsNumber reports whether the rune is a number (category N).
func IsNumber(r rune) bool {
    if uint32(r) <= MaxLatin1 {
        return properties[uint8(r)]&pN != 0
    }
    return isExcludingLatin(Number, r)
}


// IsDigit reports whether the rune is a decimal digit.
func IsDigit(r rune) bool {
    if r <= MaxLatin1 {
        return '0' <= r && r <= '9'
    }
    return isExcludingLatin(Digit, r)
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The general category is number and the sub category is decimal digit.

> [Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/standard/standard.html)
>
> [4. Character Properties](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.3.0/ch04.pdf)
>
> 4.5 General Category
>
> ```
> Nd = Number, decimal digit
> Nl = Number, letter
> No = Number, other
> ```
>
> 4.6 Numeric Value
>
> Numeric_Value and Numeric_Type are normative properties of characters
>   that represent numbers.
>
> Decimal Digits.
>
> Decimal digits, as commonly understood, are digits used to form
>   decimal-radix numbers.

For example,

[Unicode Characters in the 'Number, Decimal Digit' Category (Nd)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)

[Unicode Characters in the 'Number, Letter' Category (Nl)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm)

[Unicode Characters in the 'Number, Other' Category (No)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    digit := rune('1')
    fmt.Println(unicode.IsDigit(digit))
    fmt.Println(unicode.IsNumber(digit))
    letter := rune('Ⅷ')
    fmt.Println(unicode.IsDigit(letter))
    fmt.Println(unicode.IsNumber(letter))
    other := rune('½')
    fmt.Println(unicode.IsDigit(other))
    fmt.Println(unicode.IsNumber(other))
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
true
false
true
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know `IsDigit()` is a subset of `IsNumber()` so the result which you are getting is fine since both should evaluate to `true`. The `IsNumber` is use to determine if it is in any numeric Unicode category and `IsDigit()` checks if it is a radix-10 digit..